# SpringBoot JPA Hibernate DB Table name with a "." (period) in it

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, db2, spring-data-jpa

OK, I'm trying to connect my SpringBoot application via JPA (Hibernate) to a legacy AS/400 DB database. The table names however have a "." (Period) in them.
ex: LE.ONFP is the table name.
Hibernate however is converting the period to an underscore which causes an error because there is not table called "le_onfp".

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"LE.OFNP\"", schema = "QS36F")
```

Here is my annotations at the beginning of my Entity class.

Comment: I have also tried used `@Table(name="'LE.OFNP'", schema = "QS36F") (single quote round the table name)

Comment: and I'v tried with backticks around the table name

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37057025/jpa-entities-named-with-dot-notation

Comment: backticks before the "." is the only one that would make any sense

Answer (score 5):

adding the following line to my application.properties files fixed my issue.

`spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl`

and keeping my annotation the same.
`@Table(name = "\"LE.OFNP\"", schema = "QS36F")`